# Java - Rest Endpoint returning Image if available and JSON if not available

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, ionic-framework

I'm working on integrating a mobile front-end using the Ionic Framework and the $cordovaFileTransfer plugin.  The use case is the fetching/uploading of a person's Profile Photo.  I've got the uploading working.  It's just the fetching that's giving me some trouble.

Internally, the Cordove File Transfer plugin handles the fetching and creating of the JPG/PNG that's returned from a REST API.  In the event that an image is not available, the backend responds with an HTTP 200 OK + JSON response.  Is this the best practice?  I was thinking that the API should respond with NULL if the image is not available.  That way, I could check to see if the file size is 0 and decide on whether or not to show a default image.

Comment: Have a check at front end for image or json and then do exactly

Comment: It should be 404 for not found? Use the HTTP error codes as intended and you don't have this problem

Answer (score 1):

Your backend should respond with status code **404** if the image is not available. In the response body you can put whatever data you deem necessary.

From [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-59) (HTTP 1.1 Semantics and Content):

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists.